# Default activity not found and problems in manifest file

Tags: android

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKHUr.png)

android:default activity not found and i use the intent filter on the manifest file but it gave many errors and warnings please help me to resolve this problems The Android version is 3.0.1

Comment: Can you update your question with the AndroidManifest file?

Comment: check <intent-filter> section of your default activity in manifest. And of course post your Manifest for futher help.